# Ideas on how to integrate $\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{(a-x)(x-b)(x^2+q+px)}}$ where $a>b$

Tags: calculus, integration, inverse-function, elliptic-integrals

I am trying to integrate $$\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{(a-x)(x-b)(x^2+q+px)}},$$ where $a>b$, and $p$ and $q$ are real positive constants.

I would be very grateful if I can get some hints on how to proceed. Wolfram Mathematica tells me that this will be giving me an ellpitic integral.

Comment: Knowing $p$ and $q$ are positive reals doesn't really save us much effort here if you're going the traditional route since most of the casework depends on the sign of the discriminant, $\Delta=p^2-4q$.

Comment: If you're at all interested in learning how to reduce general elliptic integrals "by hand", you might look at https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~glabahn/Papers/ellipticPrePrint.pdf

Comment: @DavidH Thanks. The link is helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it has the structure of an Elliptic integral. You cannot solve it in terms of elementary functions, so you have to accept W. Mathematica's result, which is the only "true" result you can get.

By the way, for the curious people, the result is:

$$\frac{2 (a-x) \left(a \left(x-\sqrt{-\text{px}-q}\right)+x \sqrt{-\text{px}-q}+\text{px}+q\right) \sqrt{\frac{a \left(-x \sqrt{-\text{px}-q}+\text{px}+q\right)-(\text{px}+q) \left(\sqrt{-\text{px}-q}+x\right)}{(a-x) (\text{px}+q)}} \sqrt{\frac{(b-x) \left(a^2+\text{px}+q\right)}{(a-x) \left(a \left(b-\sqrt{-\text{px}-q}\right)+b \sqrt{-\text{px}-q}+\text{px}+q\right)}} F\left(\sin ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{\frac{(\text{px}+q) \left(\sqrt{-\text{px}-q}-x\right)+a \left(\text{px}+q+x \sqrt{-\text{px}-q}\right)}{(\text{px}+q) (a-x)}}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)|-\frac{2 (a-b) \sqrt{-\text{px}-q}}{\text{px}+q+a \left(b-\sqrt{-\text{px}-q}\right)+b \sqrt{-\text{px}-q}}\right)}{\left(a^2+\text{px}+q\right) \sqrt{\frac{a \left(x \sqrt{-\text{px}-q}+\text{px}+q\right)+(\text{px}+q) \left(\sqrt{-\text{px}-q}-x\right)}{(a-x) (\text{px}+q)}} \sqrt{(a-x) (x-b) \left(\text{px}+q+x^2\right)}}$$

**EDIT**

As suggested by @Claude Leibovici, one can write $x^2+px+q$ as $(x-c)(x-d)$ (in a way such that $q = cd$ etc...), and get the more suitable solution:

$$\frac{2 (x-b) (x-d) \sqrt{\frac{(a-b) (c-x)}{(a-x) (c-b)}} F\left(\sin ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{(a-d) (b-x)}{(b-d) (a-x)}}\right)|\frac{(a-c) (b-d)}{(b-c) (a-d)}\right)}{(b-d) \sqrt{\frac{(a-b) (a-d) (b-x) (x-d)}{(a-x)^2 (b-d)^2}} \sqrt{(a-x) (x-b) (x-c) (x-d)}}$$

**EDIT 2**

Due to some considerations, we can simplify the non Elliptic terms to get

$$-\frac{2 (b-x) (x-d) \sqrt{\frac{x-c}{(x-a) (c-b)}}}{\sqrt{\frac{(a-d) (x-b) (d-x)}{(a-x)^2}} \sqrt{(x-a) (b-x) (x-c) (x-d)}} \times \text{Elliptic Term}$$

Due to the unknown nature of $x$ and of $a$ wrt $b$ and $c$ wrt $d$, we cannot simplify it more, I believe.

**EDIT 3 - A Very Special Case**

If we assume that $x>c$, $x>a$, $c>b$, $d>a$, we get

$$\frac{-2\text{sgn}(d-x) F\left(\sin ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{(a-d) (b-x)}{(b-d) (a-x)}}\right)|\frac{(a-c) (b-d)}{(b-c) (a-d)}\right)}{\sqrt{(a-d) (-(b-c))}}$$

Comment: This can simplify a lot : replace $(x^2+px+q)$ by $(x-c)(x-d)$. Making a few simplications, it *would* fit on a single line. Try and post it, please. Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Done!!

Comment: The terms outside the elliptic integral seems to cancel out as well.

Comment: @noir1993 Now completely for it depends on the values of $x, a, b, c, d$. Imaginary things could pop out.

Comment: Thanks  for doing it. Cheers :-)